# How to terminate a windows console application that has not associated process?

Tags: windows, console

I have an application the when launched in debug mode in visual studio will some times hang but not have an associated process.

The console windows is there, but it does not respond to exit or Ctrl-C.

It prevents me from rebooting as well.

Is there a way to kill this console session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known [issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982551) with debugging in XP and Server 2003.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked with Process Explorer from Sysinternals (free) where it has a "target" that you can use to click a window and it will highlight from the list what the program is associated with to kill it or get information?

Comment: Awesome tool, thanks! Still no dice though, when I drop the target on the console window it says it is not on the process list.

Comment: I will be playing with process explorer for a while though... me likes.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the console windows just change the return type of the `main()` to `int`  and put the `return 0;` in the last of the `main()` function. console window automatically terminates.